# Position of arrow head in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

The following code draws arrows from center to some points. However, as you can see, the position of the arrow head is after the point. I want to put that before the point. How can I fix that.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a = np.array([
[-0.108,0.414],
[0.755,-0.152],
],)

x, y = a.T
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.xlim(-1,1)
plt.ylim(-1,1)

ax = plt.axes()
ax.arrow(0, 0, a[0,0], a[0,1], head_width=0.05, head_length=0.1, fc='k', ec='k')
ax.arrow(0, 0, a[1,0], a[1,1], head_width=0.05, head_length=0.1, fc='k', ec='k')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `length_includes_head=True`.

```
ax.arrow(0, 0, a[0,0], a[0,1], head_width=0.05, head_length=0.1, fc='k', 
         ec='k', length_includes_head=True)
ax.arrow(0, 0, a[1,0], a[1,1], head_width=0.05, head_length=0.1, fc='k', 
         ec='k', length_includes_head=True)
```

Output:

[image]